# InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Tags: php, google-maps

I want to pick my geo data from database. I declared the data type decimal(12,8). I want to pick the value from database this is because several click will shown the several maps.lat and lng value will change dynamically

But it shown

> InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number.
>   [

```js
<?php
if ($result!=NULL) {
 foreach ($result as $value) {
  $latitude=$value->latitude;
  $longitude=$value->longitude;
 ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function intimap(){
var mapOptions={
 center: {lat:<?php echo json_encode($latitude);?>,lng:<?php echo json_encode($longitude);?>},
 zoom: 12,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(<?php echo json_encode($value->map_name);?>),mapOptions);
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:{lat:<?php echo json_encode($latitude);?>,lng:<?php echo json_encode($longitude);?>},
  map: map,
  title:<?php echo json_encode($value->place_title);?>,
  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your relevant code. Without that, we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: @BrianKeller-Heikkila i added my code that you have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using json_encode to output your values when you set the marker variable. Just echo the values there without the json_encode and that should fix it.